How to attach core/jquery in *.libraries.yml. Can't get it working
I can add jQuery to *.libraries.yml in my Drupal 10 website using:
jquery:
  js:
    //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js: {}

and my slider and other jQuery dependent components work, but I understand the correct way to add jQuery in Drupal is by using a dependency like - core/jquery  in *.libraries.yml as per docs
Let's say I want to add jQuery for the below script using - core/jquery  in *.libraries.yml :
Slider Script

If add the following to *.libraries.yml
revo-slider:
  js:
    /assets/vendor/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    ** tried with and without - core/drupal

....the slider just won't start on my webpage. (I added revo-slider to my *.info.yml file btw)
The slider works however with:
jquery:
  js:
    //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js: {}

If you take the below script with 1000s of lines of code
/assets/vendor/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js

....are you supposed to wrap that block of code with
(function (Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.globalBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

BLOCK OF JS CODE from /assets/vendor/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js

 }
  };


...wondering how to get the slider working with - core/jquery in *.libraries.yml. I don't see jQuery being blocked anywhere.

You seem to be missing the last step: Attaching.

And a general web developer note: Adding libraries from 3rd party hosts is not a good thing as your visitors would ideally need to give their consent first before get them loaded. Try to get these libraries downloaded locally first and then add them from there.

I guess that foreign script does not work with jQuery in noConflict mode, which is enabled by default in Drupal. noConflict means you must call all jQuery functions like jQuery('div.foo').foobar() and instead of $('div.foo').foobar()

Best practice is to get third party libraries in via asset-packagist and have composer/installers put them into web/libraries/: https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/10.x/composer.json#L80-L84

I ended up wrapping a theme.js script in (function ($, Drupal) { ... })(jQuery, Drupal); and that got the slider working for me. An error $ is not a function was being displayed which pointed me to a fix. It looks like I don't need to add a core/jquery dependency to revo-slider at all as the slider is now working off the Drupal Core jQuery. Thanks for your time and advice everyone.
